# Can i use AJAX request to update the whole page like reqular http requests?

Tags: node.js, ajax, rest, crud

If i can update the whole page with AJAX when and why should i use regular `http` methods?
Can AJAX requests replace normal `http` methods?
i am using `nodeJS` `expressJS`

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Some may ask if you're updating the whole page then why use AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update the whole page using AJAX. Send request from user end and get back an JSON array from server containing all the information you want.

If you want to load data from .txt file or .html, then

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://website/some'
     , type: 'GET'
     , dataType: 'html'
    })
.done(function(data) {
  $('#container').html(data);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("Something went wrong!");
});
```

Just wondering why you are looking at AJAX when you need a complete reload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you can. But You will not ask this question once you know the use of AJAX.

For example, you will never ever update the whole page if you are using AJAX. For example, at least Navigation will remain the same and the body part will change. This is the use of AJAX and many web applications load like this. They keep navigation the same and then update rest of the web page.

You will have this kind of application where you will update the body of the page. You can use REST API to fetch the data in the form of JSON and then load this data using styling and Javascript framework like Angular, React, Backbone, etc.